# How to get String Array from JSON Object

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to get a list of available numbers from the following json object

```
 void doJSONParser(String str)
    {
        try {

            JSONObject order = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray index = order.getJSONArray("webnautes");
            for(int i = 0; i < index.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject tt = index.getJSONObject(i);

                name += "name: " + tt.getString("name")+"\n";
                phone = new String[tt.getString("phone").length()];
                //phone += "phone: " + tt.getString("phone")+"\n";
            }

            Log.d("JSON DATA:", name);
            Log.d("JSON DATA:", phone.toString());

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("JSON ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have not actually asked a question, or even explained what problem(s) you have with the posted code.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'd like to put Json objec in the String array. How do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONArray phoneJson = tt.getJSONArray("phone");
String[] arr = new String[phoneJson.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < phoneJson.length(); i++)
    arr[i] = phoneJson.getString(i);
```